# Movilizer : Using third party authentication

Tags: authentication, movilizer

Currently we have a Hybrid solution where we show a web form in our Movilizer screen. This solution does not open a new browser window, but the form is shown in the movlizer screen.

This form need to be logged in with our credentials (using our login page).

Now we have a new requirement that on referring to the form, instead of our login screen, it will be redirected to a third party authentication login. Once the user is authenticated by this third party authentication, it will be redirected to the our web form.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This must be solved first in the HTML world. Once the auth in HTML is completed (positive or negative), you can use the Movilizer specific Cordova JScript functions to provide the result to Movilizer, so the MEL logic in your Movelets can operate with it. 
Movilizer runs HTML through lightweight html engines / browser components out of the frameworks of that specific platform. In other words, Movilizer clients use functionality that the native frameworks provide ... Movilizer does not have impact on how HTML itself is processed in there. Regarding the typical problems different browsers on different platforms normally bring, this means you have to carefully test the HTML part of this process on a multitude of platforms and devices.